# InteractiveBrowserCredential authentication failed: AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid

Tags: powershell, ubuntu, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to increase access token lifetime by following [MsDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/configure-token-lifetimes#create-a-policy-and-assign-it-to-an-app).

For that I have installed powershell in ubuntu.

I have installed Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK.
And following commands.

But on command:

```
Connect-MgGraph 
    -Scopes  "Policy.ReadWrite.ApplicationConfiguration","Policy.Read.All","Application.ReadWrite.All"
```

I Microsoft page opens, After login page shows error:

> Authentication failed. You can return to the application. Feel free to close this browser tab.
>
> Error details: error invalid_scope error_description: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope 'Policy.ReadWrite.ApplicationConfiguration Policy.Read.All Application.ReadWrite.All openid profile offline_access' does not exist.

Also Terminal shows similar error:

```
Connect-MgGraph: InteractiveBrowserCredential authentication failed: The provided value for the 
input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope 'Policy.ReadWrite.ApplicationConfiguration 
Policy.Read.All Application.ReadWrite.All openid profile offline_access' does not exist.
```

I have copied command from MsDocs still show this error.

I am integrating outlook in my application. I have created application on azure and I am trying to change token lifetime for that. I am trying to login with the same account I used to create application on azure.

**UPDATE:**
[image: permissions]

As per [@Sridevi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18043665/sridevi)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78217166/19134164), I have added permissions, But how do I grant consent for that.

And trying to create user in azure portal, I got this error.
[image: azure error]

Comment: are you sure you're passing them delimited by a comma? `-Scopes Policy.ReadWrite.ApplicationConfiguration, Policy.Read.All, Application.ReadWrite.All, openid, profile, offline_access`

Comment: This is how I pass, Same as MsDocs `Connect-MgGraph -Scopes  "Policy.ReadWrite.ApplicationConfiguration","Policy.Read.All","Application.ReadWrite.All"`

Comment: @NikhilMandaliya When I ran same command in Windows PowerShell, it's working fine and connected to Microsoft Graph https://i.imgur.com/7UKSLSn.png. Could you please check and confirm what PowerShell version you installed on what Ubuntu type?

Comment: Powershell version is 7.4.1 and Ubuntu version is 20.04.6

Comment: Could you check and confirm whether the user account you are using to login have any directory role under the tenant like Global Admin etc...?

Comment: Not sure, I have not created any role. I am login with account I created app on azure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257233/discussion-between-nikhil-mandaliya-and-sridevi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, I installed PowerShell **7.4.1** version in my Ubuntu 20.04.6:

```
$PSVersionTable
```

[image]

When I tried to sign in with **personal** Microsoft (Outlook) account while connecting to Microsoft Graph, I too got **same error**:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes  "Policy.ReadWrite.ApplicationConfiguration","Policy.Read.All","Application.ReadWrite.All"
```

**Response:**

[image]

> As mentioned in this **[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/tokenlifetimepolicy-post-tokenlifetimepolicies?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=powershell#permissions)**, creating token lifetime policy using **personal** Microsoft (Outlook) accounts is [**not supported**](https://i.imgur.com/5ipBbzs.png).

To resolve the error, you need to sign in with local tenant user account with **admin** access that ends with `.onmicrosoft.com` :

[image]

After accepting **consent** to the permissions, I connected to Microsoft Graph successfully with below response:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes  "Policy.ReadWrite.ApplicationConfiguration","Policy.Read.All","Application.ReadWrite.All"
```

**Response:**

[image]

Alternatively, you can also connect to Microsoft Graph as a **service principal** by passing client ID and client secret that does not involve any user interaction.

I registered one application and granted API permissions of **Application** type by granting consent like this:

[image]

To connect Microsoft Graph as a **service principal** via PowerShell, you can make use of below sample script:

```
$appId= "appId"
$secret = "client_secret"
$tenantID = "tenantId"

$securedSecret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $secret -AsPlainText -Force
$ClientSecretCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $appId, $securedSecret

Connect-MgGraph -TenantId $tenantID -ClientSecretCredential $ClientSecretCredential
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now, you can run remaining script to create token lifetime policy like this:

```
# Create a token lifetime policy
$params = @{
    Definition = @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"4:00:00"}}') 
    DisplayName = "WebPolicyScenario"
    IsOrganizationDefault = $false
}
$tokenLifetimePolicyId=(New-MgPolicyTokenLifetimePolicy -BodyParameter $params).Id

# Display the policy
Get-MgPolicyTokenLifetimePolicy -TokenLifetimePolicyId $tokenLifetimePolicyId
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: I believe I can not create local tenant user with free account, Is it correct?

Comment: You don't have tenant then. In that case, you need to create Azure Free Trial account that gives you subscription access that will be available for 1 month with tenant directory attached. Try getting free trial subscription by clicking  `Start free`  button in this  [azure.microsoft.com/en-in/…](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/free/search/?OCID=AIDcmmf1elj9v5_SEM_f52956054c461fb1513b35dfc3227081:G:s&ef_id=f52956054c461fb1513b35dfc3227081:G:s&msclkid=f52956054c461fb1513b35dfc3227081)